# Tengo un form en un for each loop con un botón de modificar, pero al apretar el botón sólo me reconoce el primer form

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

Este es mi formulario de se repite

```
<form method="POST" id="formIdModi" name="formIdModi">
      <button type="button" name="modificar" id="modiTesti" class="btn btn-success btn-modifi">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
      </button>
 <input type="hidden" name="ratingId" id="question_id" value="<?php echo $dato['ratingId']; ?>"> 
</form>
```

[Imagen del formulario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcXTc.png)

Al apretar algun botón para editar sólo me reconoce el primer form.

[Imagen al apretar un boton de editar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w5wK.png)

Este es la función que tengo en ajax

```
<script>
        $('button[name="modificar"]').click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "consultas/datosModificar.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#formIdModi').serialize(),
                success: function (res) {
                    $('#tb').html(res);
                }
            });     
        });
</script>
```

Y aquí lo recibo

```
<?php
include('../db_connect.php');
$ratingId=$_POST['ratingId'];
$sql="SELECT ratingNumber,title,comments FROM item_rating where ratingId = '$ratingId' ";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("error base de datos:". mysqli_error($conn));
while( $resultado  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)){?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Título*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="<?php echo $resultado['title']; ?>" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Testimonio*</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="<?php echo $resultado['comments']; ?>" required></textarea>
    </div>
<?php    
}
?>
```

Siempre me toma el primer form, ya que todos comparten el mismo ID, la pregunta es como podría diferenciar cada formulario, ya que lo que me interesa es el hidden que envío a través de él.

Comment: El atributo `id` de `HTML` está pensado para ser único, ese es tu error.

Comment: En el While ingresa una variable incremental y esta la concatenas al identificador (id) del Form y los campos que contiene, de esa manera todos serán distintos.

Comment: @RobertoPaillao pero como podría reconocer ese form en específico en el Ajax?

Comment: A través de un campo hidden el cual puedes leer y en el que indicarías su id.

Comment: Cambia el tipo de botón a _submit_ y usa el evento del formulario `$('form[name="formIModi"]').on('submit', function() { ... AJAX ... });`

Comment: Lo que hice al final fue darle una clase al botón que selecciono, luego tomé el value del botón con esa clase en específico y después le quité la clase.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución que pude darle:

```
$('button[name="modificar"]').click(function (e) {
        $("#modiSection").show();
        $(this).addClass('seleccionado');
        var id = $('button[class="btn btn-success btn-modifi seleccionado"]').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "consultas/datosModificar.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { idDatos: id }, 
            success: function (res) {
                $('#tb').html(res);
            }
        });
        $(this).removeClass('seleccionado');
        $("#ratingIdx").val(id);
    });
```